# Crash from Jetpack Compose: Key il.t_7ver14 was used multiple times

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

App started to emit crash to crashlytic. I am not able simulate issue on test devices. Crash comes from Compose code. 99 % of users are ok.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Key il.t_7ver14 was used multiple times
androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl$SaveableStateProvider$1$1.invoke (SaveableStateHolderImpl.java:89)
androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl$SaveableStateProvider$1$1.invoke (SaveableStateHolderImpl.java:88)
androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffectImpl.onRemembered (Effects.kt:82)
androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl$RememberEventDispatcher.dispatchRememberObservers (Composition.kt:1137)
androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChangesInLocked (Composition.kt:828)
androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChanges (Composition.kt:849)
androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke (Recomposer.kt:625)
androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke (Recomposer.kt:537)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame (AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:41)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch (AndroidUiDispatcher.java:109)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch (AndroidUiDispatcher.java:41)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame (AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1648)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1659)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:1129)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:1045)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1622)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:958)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:230)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:319)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8893)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:608)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1103)
```

I tried to read code of jetpack compose library and find why it throws issue.

Comment: very difficult to help you out without seeing the composable function that has problems... please share it, thanks

Comment: That`s why I am asking there for help. There is no info in log about which part of app causes crashes.